# Can't write square brackets inside a table: Bad math environment delimiter

Tags: tables, brackets, underscore

I am working on this [thesis template](https://github.com/mcmanigle/OxThesis). I need to start a text with square brackets and the word inside the brackets ends with underscore, like:

```
[test]_text
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Bad math environment delimiter. \[test\_\]
```

This is the script (see the table in Section 1 where the problem is):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{ociamthesis}

\fancyfoot[C]{\emph{DRAFT Printed on \today}}  
\correctionstrue
\newcommand*{\bibtitle}{References}


\title{Suitably impressive thesis title}
\author{Your Name}
\college{Your College}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\degreedate{Michaelmas 2014}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\textbaselineskip}{22pt plus2pt}
\setlength{\frontmatterbaselineskip}{17pt plus1pt minus1pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\textbaselineskip}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{romanpages}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    My abstract here in English.
\end{abstract}


\dominitoc % include a mini table of contents
\flushbottom

% This is where the whole-document ToC appears:
\tableofcontents

%\listoffigures
\mtcaddchapter

% LIST OF TABLES
\mtcaddchapter


\end{romanpages}

\chapter{Chapter1} \label{ch:first}

\section{Section 1} \label{sec:first_sec}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ll@{\hspace{5pt}}r}
    \toprule 
    Table name & Description  \\
    \midrule 
    \[test\_\]text & another text
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use `[text]\_text`, `\[` and `\]` has special meanings, which is not what you want here.

Comment: @daleif I tried this but it does not work either, the compilation hangs and never ends if I do what you suggest.

Comment: You have several errors in your code: (a) here use `\midrule\relax` because `\midrule` can take an optional argument in `[]` so sees `[text]` as an argument, (b) you're missing a ``\\`` before the `\bottomrule. Fixing those + `[text]\_text` and your MWE works just fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things at play here.

First of `\[ ... \]` is (display) math mode. Unlike `{}` you do not need to escape `[]` to just use them. So `[text]\_text` is enough.

Secondly, macros like `\midrule` can take an optional length in `[]`'s and sadly it will scan forwards to look for such an argument. It will then see `[text]` and fail as `text` is not a length`.

One solution here is to use `\midrule\relax` to make it stop searching. But since `[text]_text` seems to be a variable of some sort, I'd probably use

```
\texttt{[text]\_text}
```

which also hides the `[]` from the argument parser.

Thirdly

```
  .. & another text
  \bottomrule
```

is wrong because you need to end the row before adding the rule, thus use

```
  .. & another text
  \\
  \bottomrule
```

(I like to place the `\\` on lines of their own as I feel this makes the code easier to read)

Comment: Thanks. The one that worked for me is: `\midrule\relax`.

Comment: @seq you can also use `\midrule{}` but that may indicate to others that `\midrule` actually takes mandatory arguments, thus why I used `\relax`